# IP location bias in places-autocomplete lib

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the places-autocomplete js library to get address suggestions.
See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete.
I use the Autocomplete class.

The documentation says

> Note: If you do not supply any bounds or a map viewport, the API will attempt to detect the user's location from their IP address, and will bias the results to that location. If you would prefer to have no location bias, set the bounds to encompass the whole world: (-90,-180),(90,180).

When I use the api with ONLY a types parameter, set to 'address', then I get suggestions from all over the world.

Why I am not getting the bias towards the location from the IP? Is this not supported together with a types parameter?

Comment: Bias means that the service will prefer results from the given bounds, but you can get prominent results from outside as well. Do you have any example that shows prominent results from an IP area are not shown?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `componentRestrictions` parameter to the config for Google Places.

eg.:

```
req.address = USER_INPUT
req.componentRestrictions = {
     country: ISO_COUNTRY_CODE
};
geocoder.geocode(req, function(results, status) {});
```

You can bias it by IP address however you will need to get the country ISO code from the IP yourself. You can do this by using a service like [IP Find](http://ipfind.co)

eg.
    `https://ipfind.co/me`

Will return a `country_code` property. The `country_code` is the ISO value that you need to pass to the google places config above. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not an answer on my question, I want to know why the default ip address biasing is not working for me.

This is what I have done as a workaround too in the meantime, but this ip biasing would be better.